# I can't login using password_hash

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I can't login using password_hash. I wan try encrypt password for more secure.In login page, firsty, will check user role. if true, it will redirect to page area follow by level id. In add-user.php, for admin adding user by form. Somebody can help me, i am new in php and mysqli languange.

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
<? 
include("connection.php");

    if ( !isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['user_pass']) ) {
    // Could not get the data that should have been sent.
    die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT user_id, user_pass, level_id, user_fullname FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_status="active" LIMIT 1')) {
    // Bind parameters (s = string, i = int, b = blob, etc), in our case the username is a string so we use "s"
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['user_name']);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Store the result so we can check if the account exists in the database.
    $stmt->store_result();
}
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
    $hashedpwd = password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $user_pass, $level_id, $user_fullname);
    $stmt->fetch();
    // Account exists, now we verify the password.
    // Note: remember to use password_hash in your registration file to store the hashed passwords.
    if ($_POST['user_pass'] === $hashedpwd) {
        // Verification success! User has loggedin!
        // Create sessions so we know the user is logged in, they basically act like cookies but remember the data on the server.
        if($level_id == '1'){
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['level_id'] = $level_id;
        $_SESSION['user_fullname'] = $user_fullname;

        header("location:../dashboard/admin/index");
        }

        if($level_id == '2'){
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['level_id'] = $level_id;

        header("location:../dashboard/manager/index");
        }

    if($level_id == '3'){
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
        $_SESSION['level_id'] = $level_id;

        header("location:../dashboard/customer/index");
        }
    }



    else {
        header("location: ../login?alert_wrong_pass=failed");
    }
} else {
    header("location: ../login?alert_wrong_pass=failed");
}
$stmt->close();

?>
```

**ADD-USER.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <?php
    include("../../functions/connection.php");

    //
    session_start();

        if($_SESSION["level_id"] !='1') {
            header("location: ../../index");
            exit();
        }

    //header
    include("header.php");  


    //insert data
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) ){
           $level_id = $_POST['level_id'];
           $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
           $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
           $hashedpwd = password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
           $user_fullname =  $_POST['user_fullname'];
           $user_email =  $_POST['user_email'];


         $addUser = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (level_id, user_name, user_pass, user_fullname, user_email )VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

                   // hubungkan data dengan variabel (bind)
                   $addUser->bind_param('issss', $level_id, $user_name, $hashedpwd, $user_fullname, $user_email);

                   if($addUser->execute()){
                    print 'Successfully inserted'; 

                }else{
                    die('Error : ('. $db->errno .') '. $db->error);
                }
        }



        ?>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar-static-side" role="navigation">

       <? //left nav bar
            include("left-nav-bar.php"); ?>

    </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
        <div class="row border-bottom">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top white-bg" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">

        <? //top nav
            include("top-nav.php");?>

        </nav>
        </div>

            <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeIn">

                <div class="p-w-md m-t-sm">
                     <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox ">
                        <div class="ibox-title">
                            <h5>Add New Users <small>| Create a new user and add them to this site</small></h5>

                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <form method="POST" action=""> 
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Username <i>(required)</i></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" name="user_name" class="form-control"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password <i>(required)</i></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="password" name="user_pass" class="form-control" name="password"></div>
                                </div>                              
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                               <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-5"><input type="email" name="user_email" class="form-control">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                               <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" name="user_fullname" class="form-control"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Roles</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <?
                                        $qSelect_db = "SELECT * FROM users_level";

                                        $result = mysqli_query ($conn, $qSelect_db);
                                        echo "<select class='form-control m-b' name='level_id'>";


                                        while($select_roles=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                                        //data stored in $drop
                                        echo "<option value=$select_roles[level_id]>$select_roles[level_name]</option>";

                                        }
                                        echo "</select>";
                                        // Close list box 
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Send User Notification <br/></label>

                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <div class="i-checks"><label> <input type="checkbox" value="">   Send the new user an email about their account.</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
                                        <button class="btn btn-white btn-sm" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" >Add user</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="ibox">



                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>

        <div class="footer">
        <? //footer 
            include("footer.php");
            ?>

        </div>
        </div>


    <?
        include("js-script.php");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. Unless this code is purely for academic reasons, it's not worth trying to fix it, security is a lot more complicated than this.

Comment: Terminology note: `mysqli` isn't a language, it's a database driver. MySQL is a database. SQL is a language.

Comment: To check the password you should use `password_verify()` and not just rehash the password and check it against the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `$_POST['user_pass'] === $hashedpwd`. You must use [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php):

```
if (password_verify($_POST['user_pass'], hashedpwd)) {
  ....
}
```

This is because `password_hash` returns a different hash every time for exactly the same password by design. This makes it impossible to guess the password based on the hash, as in using a look-up table.